# Use Reactjs app as a frontend for express nodejs in backend on domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, plesk

I created a frontend app using react js that calls an express node js api in the backend, in localhost i don't have problems because it runs on localhost, but when i deploy them both on plesk server, i don't know how to call express api from my react js app.

1.How to run express node js in production on plesk server.
2.How to call express api from react js app (in localhost i use http://localhost:8000/users)

Thank you kindly

Comment: First question can be addressed with a quick search https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/. As for the second question, is the configuration any different then when you are running on localhost? If not, do the same thing but replace localhost:8000 with your domain.

Answer (score 0):

This deployments assumes, you build your react app into your express app. So in final, your app runs on the same domain as your backend. 
E.g. if you build your react app to `reactapp` folder within your express, then you serve it with:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'reactapp/index.html'));
});
```

And on the same express you have another route for your api:

```
app.get('/api/somerestapi', (req, res) => {
  // process your api request 
  res.send({data: 'some data'});
});
```

It means, you call your API from React with relative path:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/api/somerestapi);
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, my build is in different domain, and my backend is in sub domain example:
react js build => example.com
express api => api.example.com

Comment: Will this help you? https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1087#issuecomment-262611096. Anyway i would recommend you to have everything on one domain, on one server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i will try to make it work and get back to you.

Comment: Do you know how to run express app on plesk using node js?